# C++: Including header files in each other

Tags: c++, header-files

So I have seen this question asked, but the examples people provided were extremely simple (their classes had no constructors or methods) and I don't know how to extend the solutions to a more complex case.

I have tried using forward declarations and pointers, just forward declarations, just pointers, and even forward declarations and typename definitions, all of which were suggested solutions from the other simpler posts and none of which have worked (unknown identifier or incomplete type errors). So how would I get the two files below to compile correctly and be used as I intended?

Unit.hpp:

```
#ifndef PROJECT_UNIT_HPP
#define PROJECT_UNIT_HPP

#include "GridNode.hpp"

class Unit
{
private:
    /* Fields */
    int xPos, yPos, ownerID;
    std::vector<GridNode> influenceMap;

public:
    /* Constructors */
    Unit(int x, int y, int id) : xPos(x), yPos(y), ownerID(id)
    {
        influenceMap.push_back( GridNode() );
    }

    /* Methods */
    std::vector<GridNode> getMap() {return influenceMap;}
};

#endif
```

GridNode.hpp:

```
#ifndef PROJECT_GRIDNODE_HPP
#define PROJECT_GRIDNODE_HPP

#include "Unit.hpp"

class GridNode
{
private:
    /* Members */
    int id;
    std::vector<Unit> nodeUnits;

public:
    /* Static vars */
    static int nodeLength;

    /* Constructors */
    GridNode()
    {
        std::cout << "Reached here!\n";
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: It might be a helpful exercise to first work out how to do this when putting both classes into *one* header file.

Comment: Wouldn't I reach the same problem? If I made a forward declaration of say GridNode, then defined Unit, and then fully defined GridNode, I would get another incomplete type error when I try to call any sort of constructor of GridNode, wouldn't I?

Comment: Yes, there will still be problems, but having split headers -- especially circular includes -- introduces even more complications; working out how to fix this will be easier if you solve each set of problems independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need forward declarations AND to move member function bodies (including constructors and destructors) out of the class body, and after inclusion of the other class definition.

Even implicit constructors and destructors will break things, you'll need explicit user-provided declarations (although you can use the compiler-provided definitions via `= default`)

```
class GridNode;
class Unit
{
private:
    /* Fields */
    int xPos, yPos, ownerID;
    std::vector<GridNode> influenceMap;

public:
    /* Constructors */
    Unit(int x, int y, int id);
    Unit(const Unit&);
   ~Unit();

    /* Methods */
    std::vector<GridNode> getMap();
};

#include "GridNode.hpp"

inline Unit::Unit(int x, int y, int id) : xPos(x), yPos(y), ownerID(id)
{
    influenceMap.push_back( GridNode() );
}

inline Unit::Unit(const Unit&) = default;

inline Unit::~Unit() = default;

inline std::vector<GridNode> Unit::getMap() {return influenceMap;}
```

Comment: Just for clarity, is your provided code all in one file? If so, I'm guessing it's all in the Unit.hpp file, correct? Or is it a Unit.hpp file and a Unit.cpp file? The include statement in the middle of the code block is throwing me off since I've never seen it in the middle of code.

Comment: @awar: This is a replacement for your `Unit.hpp` content, going between the `#ifndef`/`#define`/`#endif` lines.  Everything in here is already found in the `Unit.hpp` in your question, I've just changed the order.

Comment: Great thanks, one last question: why does your default constructor take in a Unit object as a parameter? Shouldn't it take no parameters?

Comment: @awar: That's not a default constructor, it's a *defaulted* copy constructor which means the compiler provides the same implementation you would get from an implicit one, except your control where the code generation happens.

Comment: I see, but why does this need to explicitly declared, the compiler won't do this automatically without these declarations? Also, this still won't compile for me, I am still getting an incomplete type error on the line "influenceMap.push_back( GridNode() );"

Comment: @awar: Did you fix `GridNode.hpp` the same way?

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I had to do for it both. I just did and it is working fine now, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is `#include <vector>` in both and forward declare `class Unit;` in `GridNode.hpp`:

```
#ifndef PROJECT_GRIDNODE_HPP
#define PROJECT_GRIDNODE_HPP

// using std::vector
#include <vector>

// Forward declare
class Unit;

class GridNode
{
private:
    /* Members */
    int id;
    std::vector<Unit> nodeUnits;

public:
    /* Static vars */
    static int nodeLength;

    /* Constructors */
    GridNode()
    {
        std::cout << "Reached here!\n";
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: The implicitly declared `~GridNode()` destructor will fail to compile correctly, since it needs to instantiate `std::vector<Unit>::~vector()` which in turn needs a full definition of `Unit`

Comment: @BenVoigt The *definition* needs `vector::~vector()`, and the destructor will only be implicitly defined when used (i.e. called).